# Помогите разобраться с замыканиями

Tags: javascript

Почему выводится

> замыканияundef

```js
function makeBuffer(){
var storage = '';

 return function (text){
 storage += text;
 return storage
 };
};
var buffer = makeBuffer();

buffer('Замыкания');
alert( buffer() );
```

Comment: А что вы ожидаете?

Comment: Хочу чтобы вывелось "Замыкания".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас все правильно. Вы вызываете функцию `buffer` два раза. В первый с параметром "Замыкания". Переменная `storage` становится равна "Замыкания". Во второй раз вы вызываете функцию без параметров (т.е. `text` = `undefined`). Переменная `storage` = `"Замыкания" + undefined;`

```js
function makeBuffer(){
var storage = '';

 return function (text){
 storage += text;
 return storage
 };
};
var buffer = makeBuffer();

alert( buffer('Замыкания') );
```

Answer (score 2):

Потому что во второй раз `buffer()` вызывается без аргументов, что способствует присваиванию переменной `text` стандартного значения `undefined` - далее при конкатенации со `storage` это значение берётся из `text` отсюда и `замыкаянияundefined` (операция `+` в данном случае превращает операнды в строку).

Answer (score 2):

В `alert` Вы вызываете `buffer` и не передаёте ему параметр, поэтому склеиваются значения "Замыкания" (задано ранее) и "`undefined`" (передано в `alert`).
Для вывода только "Замыкания" в `alert` нужно вызвать `buffer('')`.

```
function makeBuffer(){
    var storage = '';

    return function (text){
    storage += text;
    return storage
    };

};

var buffer = makeBuffer();

buffer('Замыкания')
alert( buffer('') );
```